# Imaginary number in loops with 'i' as variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have code with a loop in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), with `i` is the variable in the iteration:

```
for i = 1:n
    mycomplexexponential = exp(2*i);
    ....
end
```

The variable `i` overrides the imaginary number `i` inside of the loop. I want the `i` for *mycomplexexponential* to refer to the imaginary number.

The problem could be avoided by simply renaming the variable

```
for ii = 1:n
    mycomplexexponential = exp(2*i);
    ....
end
```

But for generic reasons, I need to keep the name of the variable as 'i'. How can I do this?

Comment: Usde `1i` (or `1j` ) for imaginary unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB convention states you do not use the multiplication operator with imaginary number symbol.
Namely, you should write:

```
mycomplexexponential = exp(2i);
```

This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Lower case `j` can also be used for the imaginary unit in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB). So your code would be

```
for i = 1:n
    mycomplexexponential = exp(2*j);
    ....
end
```

Comment: Note that even though `j` _can_ be used, `1i` or `1j` (as Luis points out) is recommended for several reasons, the main one being that you eliminate almost all possible errors (related to the complex variable name).